# Reading Content from Web Site

Tags: .net

I want to retrieve & store  information from website . The website is online shopping web site. Want to update  description , prize as per the actual link. How i can do this using .net ( I think  windows  application will be suitable for the same.)

I tried below code, but always getting exception

> "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."

```
url = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["url"].ToString();
var webClient = new WebClient();.
```

Sample URL is http://www.flipkart.com/royal-son-what0355-wayfarer-sunglasses/p/itmeyx9ymutgg7k7?pid=SGLEYX9YDYFYAZAE&otracker=hp_mod_lifestyle_new-arrivals_prd_img

Comment: More information is needed. As it stands now, your question is a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to set a user-agent on the webclient before using it to load the website.

See below. I've used the user-agent string for chrome 37

```
var str = "http://www.flipkart.com/royal-son-what0355-wayfarer-sunglasses/p/itmeyx9ymutgg7k7?pid=SGLEYX9YDYFYAZAE&otracker=hp_mod_lifestyle_new-arrivals_prd_img";

    var client = new WebClient();

    client.Headers.Add("user-agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36");

    var ret  = client.DownloadString(new Uri(str));
```

If you are interested in "scraping" specific parts of this page you'll want to use a tool like HtmlAgilityPack to help you do that.